# Find xpath and get the value from anchor tag in selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium-rc

I have been working on java project which needs the selenium testing tool for running the test class. As per the requirement, I need to know how to write the xpath, and how to get the value (goodluck) using xpath for given tag.

```
<span class="clienthome" id="personTableForm:foundClientsTable:0:j_id118">
                        goodluck</span>
```

Please anyone kindly help me.

Comment: You neeed to paste a complete xml and tell us if you need only content of this particular span or all spans of class clienthome.

Answer (score 0):

try - //span[@class='clienthome']/.[normalize-space(text())='goodluck']

or

//span[normalize-space(text())='goodluck']